# 2 Factor Authentification for sites in Linux program

Tags: 2-factor-authentication

Github demands that I use 2 Factor Authentication. Github proposes to use one of these:

- https://support.1password.com/one-time-passwords/
- https://authy.com/guides/github/
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/mobile-authenticator-app

I would like to not use my phone, but a program on my Kubuntu. Basically, I would like to screenshot, instead of using my phone. Is this possible and with what program?

Comment: do you understand what the **2** in 2 factor authentication actually means?

Comment: KeePassCX does OTP & runs on Linux, there are also many more. You really need to do a bit of searching for before asking a question.

Comment: @JaromandaX: My understand is that there are two different means of authentication. Here, one is password-based (which is stored in my brain + github's database) and one is device-based (sort of - ultimately we are also talking about software on that device). Meaning, if someone only got the password, the person would not get access. So, the attacker would need also to have access to the device. The device could by my phone - if the attacker gets my phone or hacks it, bad luck for me. Or the device could by my laptop - if the attacker gets my laptop or hacks it, bad luck for me. Do I miss sth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! Both KeepassXC and pass(1) (password-store) can do TOTP OTP. You will need the code from the QR code, many sites let you see it directly instead of having to process the QR code. But you can also decode the QR code with a QR code decoder program.

However, note that those usually don't store the encryption keys for those in a secure hardware enclave unlike it is assumed about the handheld devices.

Answer (score 0):

I use this [web-based app called Gauth](https://gauth.apps.gbraad.nl/#main). There's also a [GitHub site](https://github.com/gbraad-apps/gauth) that explains it, and an alternative for self-hosting the app.

I mostly dislike 2FA, but this app makes it *less bad* :)

Comment: im again wondering if i should have had checkboxed making this a Community Wiki

Comment: @MikaFeiler: Yeah- maybe... but wouldn't you have to share all of those reputation points?   :)